# How can I update my view controller's UILabel through another class?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I'm my class i've added a an instance of my view controller, created a property and then synthesized it in my implementation file. I am trying to update the UIlabel in the view controller like this,

```
NSString *currentChar = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%c", ch];
viewController.outputLabel.text = currentChar;
[currentChar release];
```

My problem is that everything builds without any errors or warnings but the label just doesn't get updated, what am I doing wrong. I'd really appreciate some help on this one.

Comment: Are you trying to set this label before it is actually loaded? Where is this code?

Comment: the above code is in a separate class. And I create an instance of that class in the viewDidLoad method of my view controller.

Comment: see my answer below.  Be sure you're not instantiating a new instance of viewController and using the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're referencing the existing viewController and you didn't instantiate a new one?  Your property is not declared as copy, correct?

textProcessor.h / .m

```
@interface textProcessor : NSObject {

MainViewController *mainView;

}

@property (retain) MainViewController *mainView;

@end

@implementation textProcessor;
@synthesize mainView;
```

MainViewController.h / .m

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {

UILabel *myLabel;

}
@property (retain) UILabel myLabel;

@end

@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize myLabel;
```

When you are initializing your textProcessor class, and you set the value for "mainView" like

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textProcessor *proc = [[textProcessor alloc] init];
    proc.mainView = self;
    //note that you are not doing this:
    //MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    //proc.mainView = mainView;
    //that was creating a new instance variable instead of using self, the existing one
    [textProcessor release];
}
```

Comment: well I guess i'm instantiating a new one in my class's init method. And no the property is not set to copy, my property is like this: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *outputLabel;...You seem to be onto something so what should I do?

Comment: I'm interested in the @property to your viewController.  You are trying to reference the existing viewController so you can get the label on it.  I'm wondering if you're mistakenly instantiating a new viewController, accessing the label on that, instead of the one you want.  What is the name of your custom class?

Comment: So I have MainViewController.m and then I have textProcessor.m. The property I declared is in MainViewController.m and then in the -(id) init method of textProcessor.m I create an instance of MainViewController.

Comment: When you create the instance variable for textProcessor, where do you do that? The appDelegate? Also, you should have two properties in two classes.  the myLabel property in MainViewController, and the viewController property in textProcessor.m

Comment: I create the instance for textProcessor in the view did load method of the view controller. And I also did create a property for viewController in textProcessor.h

Comment: so do this: i edited my answer. set the value of the mainView property of textProcessor to "self" like proc.mainView = self;

Comment: oh I think I see what you mean, i'm not actually setting the mainView property to self. I'm just doing textProcessor *proc = [[textProcessor alloc] init];

Comment: yes, textProcessor should have a property for MainViewController, and MainViewController should have a property for a UILabel called myLabel.  If you are working in the viewDidLoad of MainViewController, and you instantiate textProcessor, make sure you refer to "self" which is a pointer to the class you are currently in.  I get the feeling you were instantiating a new MainViewController

Comment: Yes that exactly what i was doing, I was creating a NEW instance of the MainViewController. So I just tried setting the property to self and it works perfectly!!! Thank a  lot for your help :) I can't believe how simple it was lol

Comment: if you could be so kind as to click the checkmark on my answer =) good luck sir

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your label in IB? If you are using IB you have to create an IBOutlet for your UILabel. You then make a connection between the UILabel in IB to your IBOutlet in your class.

Comment: Well I created an IBOutlet in the view controller and I can access and modify it no problem when I do it from the view controlle e.g. self.outputLabel.text = @"...";

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the `setNeedsDisplay` method on the view?  Also you may want to try using the `setText` method instead of assigning directly to the property.

Comment: well i just tried this but it did not work,  viewController.outputLabel.text = phrase;
[viewController.view setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: [viewController.outputLabel setText:phrase]; I also tried that but it did not work